# Error al tratar de cargar mapa en un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, fragment

se me está presentando un problema al cargar Maps, estoy haciendo uso de SupportMapFragment, no muestra ningún error visible en el código pero en Logcat me muestra el siguiente error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Rutas.onViewCreated(Fragment_Rutas.java:43)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error se genera desde aquí:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
       getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

El código del Fragment es el siguiente:

```
public class Fragment_Rutas extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public Fragment_Rutas() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rutas, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //SupportMapFragment mapFragment2 = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    //mapFragment2.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) getActivity());

    //MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    //fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override//acercamiento
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 16.1f));
}
}
```

A continuación muestro el archivo XML donde tengo la etiqueta MapFragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Rutas"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#94dea7">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"></fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

El código completo está aquí:

**[Fragment_Rutas](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tecnologias/uniagustapp/fragmentos/Fragment_Rutas.java)**

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Sustituye `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` por `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`.

Comment: Me pone en rojo en el layout SupportMapFragment

Comment: @David Tambien usé:     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: Entonce en el Layout coloca en rojo SupportMapFragment‌​ Unresolved Class

Comment: mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); creo que el error está aquí

Comment: Coloca `getActivity()` en vez de `this`.

Comment: mapFragment2.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) getActivity()); ya habia hecho esto acabo de hacerlo con el nuevo cambio en XML, entonces el error lo muestra asociado al inflate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema como comentas, se genera en este punto:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
       getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

no puedes llamar el método `getMapAsync()`, ya que genera un error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(

Ya que en realidad no esta obteniendo la referencia de la vista map.
Para evitar este problema te sugiero inflar la vista dentro de `onCreateView()` y ahí obtén la referencia del Map, para posteriormente llamar  `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` :

```
/* @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rutas, container, false);
}*/

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rutas, container, false);

    //Si usas getActivity estas suponiendo que la vista se buscara en el layout cargado por la Activity.
    //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;    

}
```

dentro de `fragment_rutas.xml` debes tener el `framgment` con el id map :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya antes me habías ayudado a resolver una pregunta similar casi identica, con la diferencia que ahora estoy usando SupportMapFragment y adicionalmente de estar usando el método OnViewCreate nuevamente XD, tambien estaba usando getSupportFragmentManager(). ya apliqué las correcciónes y quedó perfecto y mas claro.

Comment: Y adicionalmente muchas gracias por agregar comentarios al la solución. ;D

Comment: Excelente @Alfredo , me da gusto mi respuesta ayudo a solucionar tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Al crear un fragment desde otro fragment debes buscarlo con el metodo getChildFragmentManager() de la siguiente manera:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Agrego algo importante:
Si declaras la inicialización de un fragment desde un layout xml, este se va a generar siempre con el mismo id lo que genera inconsistencias en la reacreación automática de android, ejemplo, cuando reemplazas el fragment principal por otro y después haces un pop del backstack.
Para resolver este tema tenes que remover el fragment al momento de destruir la vista para que en su recreación no te genere una excepción por ids de fragment repetidos ;)

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f!=null)
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(f).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, quedó solucionado mi problema usando el getChildFragmentManager() como me indicas, adicionalmente lo usé en el método onCreateView.